# How to manipulate indices in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, indexing

I am trying to use tf.gather_nd to convert

```
'R = tf.eye(3, batch_shape=[4])'
```

to :

```
array([[[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0.]]], dtype=float32)'
```

With the index:

```
ind = array([[0, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

I found out if I can convert the index matrix to something like:

```
ind_c = np.array([[[0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 1]], 
               [[1, 2], [1, 1], [1, 0]], 
               [[2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 0]], 
               [[3, 0], [3, 2], [3, 1]]])
```

gather_nd will do the job. so my question is:

1. is there a better way than converting the index ind to ind_c
2. if this the only way how I can convert ind to ind_c with tensorflow? (I have done this for now manually)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
ind = tf.constant([[0, 2, 1],[2, 1, 0],[1, 2, 0],[0, 2, 1]], dtype=tf.int32)

# Creates the row indices matrix
row = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(ind)[0]), 1), [1, tf.shape(ind)[1]])

# Concat to the ind to form the index matrix
ind_c = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(row,-1), tf.expand_dims(ind, -1)], axis=2)
```